# Simple Software for drawing shapes

Tags: javascript, drawing

I'm looking for a simple application for drawing shapes like [this one on Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/drawing-basics/p/challenge-simple-shapes):

[image]

I want to be able to use a simple language (javascript ideally) to draw shapes and test algorithms. My preference would be a windows desktop app but a web app will also be ok. I'd like to be able to share the code/drawing with other people too.
I would be mainly using the application for 2d spatial geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention Khan academy, which seems to a be a neat resource providing examples using a wrapper around the [processing.js](//processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html) library. To quickly be able to draw examples and stuff using this library I would suggest using [jsFiddle](//jsfiddle.net), which both allows for drawing and testing of algorithms, and sharing of code and/or drawing with other people.

The following two main sections are one displaying a basic setup of jsFiddle for usage with processing.js, and one with some different resources which you might find helpful.

### Setup of basic processing.js fiddle

In the four subsections below I provide the setup for [this basic example](//jsfiddle.net/n7m5vr0o/) of a jsfiddle providing access to the commands from Khan Academy, which you can fork into other examples.

For starters change the draw function to your liking, and hit the `run` button in the toolbar to see your changes.

#### Frameworks & Extensions

Select "Processing.js 1.0.0" or other suitable version, and in the next dropdown select "No wrap in <body>"

#### Html (upper left box)

```
<canvas width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

#### Css (upper right box)

Notice the trick to end the style section using `&lt;/style&gt;` at start, and reverse at end to include a little script snippet to make the javascript box tidier.

```
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    var scripts = document.body.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var canvases = document.body.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
    new Processing(canvases[0],scripts[0].text);
}, false);
// Here prevent javascript in body from throwing error
</script>
<style>
```

#### Javascript (lower left box)

```
 // Setup the Processing Canvas
 void setup(){
   size( 400, 400 );
 }

 // Main draw loop
 void draw(){

  rect(10, 20, 100, 150);
  rect(90, 140, 30, 30);
  ellipse(130, 130, 100, 200);
  ellipse(130, 130, 110, 110);
  line(0, 200, 100, 0);

 }
```

### Some other resources

Whilst looking for alternatives for you question, I found some resources which I'll recommend for further reading:

- [Running Khan Academy programs on your computer](//www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/running-khan-academy-programs-your-computer) – Quote: *I've noticed a lot of people asking how they can run the programs they've seen or created on Khan Academy's computer science area, so I've written this post to explain how to (sort of) achieve it. Note that not all Khan Academy programs will run on your computer*
- [jsFiddle Documentation](//doc.jsfiddle.net/index.html) – A work in progress, but there does exist a tutorial, a FAQ and some usage examples
- [A jsFiddle clock using processing.js](//jsfiddle.net/n2yUg/) – Displaying animation using processing.js
- StackOverflow question: [JavaScript: Displaying Graphics like rect(), triangle(), ellipse(), etc](//stackoverflow.com/questions/22950665/javascript-displaying-graphics-like-rect-triangle-ellipse-etc) – Which links and describes some stuff related to how Khan Academy works, and with some info on a standalone program, and some download instructions, and so on...
- [Processing.js Quick Start - JavaScript Developer Edition](//processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html) – Describes a little on history of processing.js, but quickly turns into useful information on how to use processing.js in different contexts. This seems to be the authoritative documentation on processing.js as well.